# Fill @Html.EditorFor from model using JSON on change @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I want to fill `EditorFor` fields that contain information about a room and save data if it has changed. For choosing a particular room in the list, data in fields changed.

My view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, ViewBag.roomlist as SelectList, "Select room",new { @id = "ddlRoom"})

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditRoom", "Admin", new { id = 0 }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <p>Number room:</p>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberRoom)
        <p>Category:</p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Categoryid, ViewBag.catlist as SelectList, "Select Category")
        <p>Cost per night</p>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CostPerNight)
        <p>Number of seats</p>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfSeats)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="icon save" />
    }
```

JSON in view:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ddlRoom').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Admin/EditRoomResult/' + $('#ddlRoom').val(),function (data) {
                var tmp=data;
                $("#CostPerNight").val('data.CostPerNight'); //not work
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult EditRoomResult(int id)
{
    var distinct = _roomService.GetRoom(id);
    return Json( distinct, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Service:

```
public IQueryable<Room> GetRoom(int id)
{
    var tmp=_context.Room.Where(m => m.Id == id);
    return tmp;
}
```

How to get the value field `CostPerNight` from `var distinct` in controller or `data` in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `$("#CostPerNight").val('data.CostPerNight');` is setting the value of the input to the string `"data.CostPerNight"`. Assuming `CostPerNight` is a property of the model you are returning, then it needs to be

```
$('#ddlRoom').change(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Admin/EditRoomResult/' + $('#ddlRoom').val(),function (data) {
        $("#CostPerNight").val(data.CostPerNight); // no quotes
    });
});
```

Side note: I recommend you use the following format to ensure your url is correctly constructed (using `@Url.Action()`) and avoid unnecessarily traversing the DOM again (by using `$(this).val()`)

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("EditRoomResult", "Admin")', { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
```